Receiving CORS error from website to opayo
I have been having an issue with our .NET website - it has a small purchase option integrated with Opayo. Currently a customer can enter all the card details - hit submit and then we receive the CORS error shown below:
CORS error
When I ask Opayo they say it is our website, the web devs say it is opayo!
Any help greatly appreciated.
Chris
When we turn CORS off manually payments will go through

The error indicates that the Opayo API isn't including the necessary headers to allow your website to access it. CORS is enforced by browsers to prevent unauthorized cross-origin requests, so if Opayo's server doesn’t include the required header, your browser will block the request. It can happen  due to the blocked request or could indicate another issue such as a network failure, but it's related to the CORS issue.

This question is similar to: Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) concept. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.  (Edit: Among many other potential duplicates.  Searching the error message and CORS in general will help you find a lot of information.)
